# Как сохранить скопированные файлы с переименованием имени

Tags: python

Вопрос заключается в переименовании копируемого файла, а именно, чтобы имя содержал дату копирования(не критично). Есть каталог откуда нужно ежедневно забирать файлы и пере сохранять в другую директорию, но что бы имя файла менялось и не перезаписывал имеющиеся файлы в данном каталоге.
Я в программировании новичок и только учусь, перепробовал все варианты shutil, но максиму что смог это скопировать, заменить, создать и т. д.
Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно скопировать файлы с одной папки в другую, но при этом поменять имена копируемых файлов. К примеру, ест папка в которой содержатся файлы  с расширением csv, мне нужно ежедневно копировать их в другую папку ( так как источник ежедневно обновляется) и собирать все это добро в другой папке. А чтобы они в дальнейшем не перезаписывались, нужно постоянно их переименовывать на дату записи.

Answer (score 1):

Я новичок. Вот такой вариант у меня получился по вашим условиям.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Настоящий скрипт делает копии файлов заданного каталога в выбранный каталог,
# присваивает новому файлу имя, которое содержит дату создания родительского файла
# 

# Импортиируем модули
import os
import datetime
import shutil

# задаем расположение каталогов
url = 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Downloads\\'
target_url = 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Downloads\\Test\\'
filename = 'anagram-1.0.py'

# получаем день создания файла
def get_time(url, filename):
    '''
    Принимает имя файла
    Возвращает время создания файла, тип данных - 'datetime.date'
    '''
    t = os.path.getmtime(url + filename)
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)

# копирование файла, когда методанные и содержимое копируется
def copy_file(url, filename, target_url, day):
    """
    Принимает имя исходного файла, день создания
    Копирует файл в новый каталог с новым именем
    """
    str_day = str(day.date())
    shutil.copy2(url + filename, target_url + filename[:-2] + '_' + str_day + '.py')
    return

day = get_time(url, filename)
copy_file(url, filename, target_url, day)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Comment: как думаете, если расположение источника будет ftp сервер, код будет работать ?

Comment: просто думал совместить все в один код, так как я с начало забираю все с ftp сервера себе на локальный диск

Comment: Я новичок. Не пробовал работать с ftp сервером. Простите, не подскажу. Нужно читать документацию.

Comment: интересно, если мы говорим о каталогах и что внутри, то почему код выдает ошибку и сообщает что не нашел файл с таким именем, мы же не ищем в конечном каталоге файл с новым созданным именем ...

Comment: Я написал код за 40 минут, чтобы помочь вам. Его можно чуть докрутить под вашу задачу, изменить имена каталогов. Я новичок.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, это не критика, вы мне очень помогли, дали направление